# Numpy elementwise greater (for each element in another array)

Tags: python, numpy, list-comprehension

I struggle to write find the best "question" so please feel free to suggest another title.

Lets say I have `a=np.array([5,3,2,4])` and `b=np.array([1,2])` - I want to get a list of list (or np.arrays) with the value of `a>b[i]` i.e it can be written as a list comprehension

`[a[i]>p for p in b]` which returns

`[np.array([True,True,True,True]), np.array([True,True,False,True])]`. Since I have a rather large data set I hoped that there was a numpy function to do such, or is list comprehension the better way here?

Comment: If the array `a` is really large (close to your memory limit), you may want to process `a > b[i]` separately anyway and in that case I would look no further than a simple loop, which is slow but can have a small memory footprint. Otherwise, you can use broadcasting which is fast but has a large memory footprint. List-comprehension in this case has both disadvantages: slow and large memory footprint.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `numpy` broadcasting for this, you just need to add an extra dimension into each of your arrays:

```
>>> a[None,:] > b[:,None]
array([[ True,  True,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True, False,  True]])
```